# how to re-initialize a div position when filtered from N such div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is small code.

**X.html**

```
<input type="text" id="search-criteria"/>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search"/>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Services</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-warning">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Branches</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Firm Type</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-success">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Designations</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**X.js**

```
$('#search-criteria').keyup(function(){
    $('.misc').hide();
    var regex = new RegExp($('#search-criteria').val(), 'i');
    $('.misc').filter(function() {
       return regex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
});
```

I tried with the code above and it is working,  But, The problem is that the position of the div is not refreshed, it must be initialized to start of page. There are many div with class `misc`. After searching the expected div, it 
 is visible but remains at the same position. I want it's position to be re-initialized and when I clear the search input, all must be visible as they were.

Below is the supporting image,

**NO SEARCH**

[image]

**AFTER SEARCH**

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: You need to target the parent container col-sm-3. In Jquery $('.misc').parent().hide()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only hiding the divs *inside* your column layout, so the columns are still being displayed at their widths. You should hide the `col-sm-3` divs to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the columns not the element inside the column. Just use `parent()` on the `.misc` elements. Like this:

```js
$('#search-criteria').keyup(function(){
    var regex = new RegExp($('#search-criteria').val(), 'i');
    var elements$ = $('.misc').parent();
    elements$.hide().filter(function() {
       return regex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<input type="text" id="search-criteria"/>
<input type="button" id="search" value="search"/>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-info">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Services</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-warning">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Branches</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Firm Type</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="misc">
      <div class="box box-success">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
           <h3 class="box-title">Designations</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cyrix. I know your solution will work. But Ultimately I am playing with `col-sm-3`. But Still upvoted ur answer, as it is yet another path to acheive solution.

Answer (score 0):

try change the structure like this

```
<div class="misc">
 <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="box box-info">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
       <h3 class="box-title">Services</h3>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```